# wp7 keyboard - collapse button

Tags: windows-phone-7

I understand the Metro theme and have read the UI design guide from Microsoft regarding WP7 applications.  I am really missing a button on the SIP for collapsing the keyboard.  On Android phones, this button is available on the SIP.  Pressing the back button on the phone while you are in the textboxes hides the keyboard, but that is not obvious.
Any InputScope for which this kind of button shows up?

Scenarios like when you are connecting with Twitter or Facebook and performing OAuth, web browser shows the login screens from the provider and we have not control over where the textboxes for accepting credentials should be displayed.  Without a collapse button on the SIP, the user will have to tap out of the textboxes to get to the Login screen from those provider authentication pages.

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feared that there is no InputScope that does that.  John, when designing our pages - we can certainly abide by the UI guidelines but for certain scenarios, it is really necessary and useful at the same time - try performing an OAuth operation with Facebook and Twitter and you will see what is happening and how a collapse SIP button could help.

Mick, I will post the suggestion on connect.

Pratik

Answer (score 4):

like you said, The `Back` physical  button on the phone always closes the SIP, without navigating.  People will start to learn it and it will be second nature, and then a button that closes the SIP is just a waste of space.

Answer (score 2):

Set InputScope to Search to add an Enter button.

Do this is in the Key Up to close the SIP:

```
    private void TextControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the available InputScope types from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx). Sadly, I am pretty sure that none of them have the collapse button you are referring to.

The only work around I know of is to use the back button. It is not ideal at all, but maybe something better will come around in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no InputScope which provides a dedicated button for this purpose. It would not hurt to comment in their suggestion forum or on connect though.

Comment: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68601/418745.aspx - i have posted the suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap on the screen to scroll, or in an empty space usually to get the SIP to go away.  There is no button to do it.  I agree one should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Users just need to hit the back button to make the keyboard go away.  Once people learn that behavior having a dedicated button for that behavior would just be a waste of space.